# Trigger MsgBox upon first entry of cell, do nothing on subsequent changes or clicks of the cell

Tags: excel, vba

Update:

I have removed the original question text as that is resolved, but has lead to a new question.

My code is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A15")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "something changed"
End If

End Sub
```

This triggers the MsgBox when I click on the cell for the first time, which is great, but subsequent changes or clicks to that cell also triggers, and I'm trying to make it so it only triggers on the first click/first entry of data, subsequent changes or clicks to the cell should do nothing

Comment: Is it in the sheet module? Right-click the sheet tab, View Code and paste there.

Comment: Ah that's why! I've never had to work with sheet modules before, so thanks for that. It works now, but the only remaining issue is I'd like to make it so it's not so much a 'change' to the cell but 'upon insertion'. So an action (like a MsgBox) happens when something in typed in, and doesn't happen again if the cell has been changed (meaning, I don't want the action to keep repeating if the cell is updated, only when a value is first entered)

Comment: Do you mean if the cell goes from being empty to non-empty?

Comment: Yep, exactly that. And actually, as you write that, I'm thinking I could do that with an if statement IsEmpty - would that be the best approach?

Comment: To capture the contents before you change the cell you'll need to use the SelectionChange event too. There are examples online - why not give it a try and post back if you get stuck.

Comment: So I've used SelectionChange, but it still triggers when the existing value is changed, in fact it triggers even if i select the cell when a value is typed in. I'm looking for it to ONLY ever trigger upon the first entry of data, any changes do not result in a trigger. Is there anything that does this? I'll update my main question with my code

Comment: You need SelectionChange to trap the value when you select the cell AND change to trap the value after the cell has been changed. If you want the code to run only once I think you'll have to place a value in a cell somewhere to monitor this (could be on a hidden sheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not indicated if this is the only Event macro you are using or if there are others.  If this is the **only one**, then:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A15")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "something changed"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

The code above acts like a mousetrap.  Once it snaps, it must be reset manually.  So after you have completed edits to the event code, run this manually:

```
Sub ReEnableEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This works and doesn't repeat if the same cell is modified numerous times, however, once it is triggered, if I edit the code and change it to A16, it doesn't seem to trigger anymore, it's like its only replicable once

Answer (score 1):

If you want a MsgBox to appear the first time you click on a cell, an easy way to do that would be to check if the cell is empty before calling the MsgBox.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing _
   And IsEmpty(Target) Then

    MsgBox "something changed"

End If

End Sub
```

But then what happens if the user clicks on the cell, the MsgBox shows, but the user doesn't enter any value into the cell? Do you want to show the MsgBox again the next time they click on it or not?

If you don't want to show it again, then rather than testing if the cell is empty, I would fill a global range with all the cells that have been clicked so far. Then you would only need to check if the cell is already contained in the range.

```
Public clickedCells As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

' if the selected cell is one of the relevant cells
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then

'   usual procedure if the range of clicked cells is still empty
    If clickedCells Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "something changed"
        Set clickedCells = Target

    Else

'       if the range of clicked cells is not empty, then check if selected cell is contained in it
        If Intersect(Target, clickedCells) Is Nothing Then

            MsgBox "something changed"

            ' write selected cell into range
            Set clickedCells = Union(clickedCells, Target)

        End If

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

p.s.: Do you want to show the MsgBox after a value has been typed in a cell for the first time, or at the time of selecting the cell for the first time? Because if it's the former, you should use the 'Change' event instead of 'SelectionChange'.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```